# Unable to test add_action in perfex CRM

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook, action

I'm trying to add the hook in perfex CRM to enable or trigger the action **after_invoice_added.** if the invoice is created *i do not find the file* **add_invoice.log** in folder; the hooks are enabled/true; and with the code method to call $data variable posted in invoice

> $contents = $this->CI->output->get_output();

Will it bring the $data along with the function.

```
hooks()->add_action('after_invoice_added','my_after_invoice_added');

function my_after_invoice_added($id) {


          <script>
alert( 'Hello, world!' );
```

}

it might be not the common issue; you can find the perfex CRM guide for the reference : [Hooks](https://www.perfexcrm.com/knowledgebase/action-hooks/)

[Screenshot containing the trigger required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgrRo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it like that

```
hooks()->add_action('after_invoice_added','my_after_invoice_added', 10);
```

```
function my_after_invoice_added($id) {        
     echo ( 'Hello, world!' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after_invoice_added hook is already added by perfex crm so you just need to do a actions as below. hope this works for you.

```
hooks()->do_action('after_invoice_added','my_after_invoice_added');
function my_after_invoice_added($id) {        
     echo ( $id);
}
```